# Solving a boundary value problem (diffusion-reaction equation) with scipy solve_bvp

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I'm struggling to solve the following 2nd order boundary value problem:

```
y'' + 2/x*y' + k**2.0*F(y) = 0

y(x=1)=1,  y'(x=0)=0

F(y) = -y or F(y) = -y*exp(AB*(1-y)/(1+B(1-y))
```

I somehow fail to set the boundary conditions right. I defined the function for `F(y)=y` and boundary conditions the following way:

```
def fun(x, y, p):
 k = p[0]
 return np.vstack((y[1], -2.0/x*y[1] + k**2.0*y[0]))

def bc(ya, yb, p):
     return np.array([ya[0], yb[0],ya[1]])

y[0,:] = 1
y[1,0] = 0
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y, p=[40])
```

The results should I get are definitely wrong, changing the initial conditions doesn't make things better. I think my problem is some how related to the zero gradient boundary condition at x=0. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here a MWE, which should give a constant value of 1 for k=0.01. but for a k=5, the value at x=0 should be approx. 0.06:

```
def fun(x, y, p):
     k = p[0]
     return np.vstack((y[1], -2.0/x*y[1] + k**2.0*y[0]))

def bc(ya, yb, p):
     return np.array([ya[0], yb[0]-1.0,yb[1]])

x = np.linspace(1e-3, 1, 100)
y = np.zeros((2, x.size))
y[0,:] = 1

from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y, p=[1000])
x_plot = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_plot = sol.sol(x_plot)[0]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot)
```

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The (implied) sign in the last term changes from formula to code. Which version is the correct one? If the code variant is correct, that is, `F(y)=-y`, then indeed `k=5` results in `y0=0.06743870030718753`.

Comment: Actually, I your're right. I missed the minus sign in the above equation. I guess this also affects you answer  below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case `F(y)=y`. Then it is easy to see that the basis solutions of this linear ODE are `sin(k*x)/x` and `cos(kx/x)`. Similarly for `F(y)=-y` one gets `sinh(k*x)/x` and `cosh(k*x)/x`. This means that most solutions have a singularity at `x=0`. Such a singularity is almost impossible to handle out-of-the-box for standard ODE solvers. One has to help the solver at the singularity, normal procedure applies again at some distance from the singularity.

What you can do is to analyze the situation at `x=0` and move away a little bit.
You get via limit of difference quotients

```
y''(0) + 2*y''(0) + k^2*F(y(0)) = 0
```

which allows you to compute a quadratic Taylor polynomial. Thus solve the problem on `[a, 1]` with the ODE solver using the continuation to the singularity `y(x)=y(0)-k**2/6*F(y(0))*x**2` on `[0,a]`.

The boundary condition at `x=a` is easiest to establish with treating `y0=y(0)` as parameter. The ODE and BC functions then are

```py
def ode(x,y,y0): return [ y[1], -2*y[1]/x - k**2*F(y[0]) ]
def bc(ya,yb,y0): y2 = -k**2*F(y0)/6; return [ ya[0] - y0 - y2*a**2, ya[1] - 2*y2*a, yb[0]-1 ]
```

In the cases discussed in the question, this gives

```py
a = 1e-2
def F(y): return -y

for k in [0.01, 5]:
    res = solve_bvp(ode, bc, [a,1], [[1,1], [0,0]], p=[1], tol=1e-5)
    print(f'k={k}: {res.message}, y0={res.p[0]}, theory: {k/np.sinh(k)}')
    if res.success:
        y0 = res.p[0]
        x = np.linspace(a,1,61);
        plt.plot(x, res.sol(x)[0])
        plt.plot([0], [y0],'o', res.x, res.y[0],'+', ms=4)
        plt.title(f'k={k}'); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

with the result

> k=0.01: The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy., y0=0.9999833335277726, theory: 0.9999833335277757
>
> [image: plot of solution]
>
> k=5: The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy., y0=0.06738256929427147, theory: 0.06738252915294544
>
> [image: plot of solution]

Comment: Thank you Lutz for the explanation! It works fine for `F(y)` being y or -y. But there are some troubles with `F(y)=-y exp(ab(1-y)/(1+beta*(1-y)))`
I get singular Jacobians or I run out of grid points for high values of `k`. I guess the complex form of `F(y)` causes the problems. Do you have any ideas on that? I gonna try to increase the grid points  later.

Comment: Can you give some typical values for k and A,B or alpha,beta? If these are small, the problem should still be close to the linear DE, with the solution a small perturbation of it. For larger values you get the general problem that a boundary value problem, like any non-linear equation, can have no or multiple solutions.

Comment: @mboe : I corrected a stupid sign error in the `bc` function that reduced the order of the first segment from 3 to 1. Now the linear case works even better, does it also repair the non-linear case somewhat?

Comment: I've tested the modified boundary condition. For the `F(y)=-y exp(ab(1-y)/(1+b(1-y))` case the modified code gives solutions for larger `k` than before, but fails above `k>0.7` for `a=10, b=0.8` 

Typical values from similar problems in literature are `a < 40 and -1<b<1`, A and B in the original post were defined as `A=ab, B=b` to be consistent with the initial question.

Comment: Increasing `k` in small steps from `k=1` on and using the solution of the previous `k` as initial guess for the new `k` I could go to `k=5` with the above parameters. The solution seems to develop a boundary layer at `x=1` for the larger `k`, staying close to zero for `x<0.5`.

Comment: I checked your approach and it worked out for `F(y)=y exp(AB(1-y)/(1+B(1-y))`, but the problem is that the expression should also include the minus before `y`. For that case I just get results for `k<0.4`.
I guess solve_bvp can only handle linear problems. I re-checked recent literature on this problem and there shooting methods were used to solve this problem.

Comment: solve_bvp uses multiple shooting with adaptive refinement, and my approach worked with the minus sign using the steps `k in [0.01, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0]`.

Comment: Ok, I did not konw that solve_bvp uses a shooting method.
I systematically tried to evaluate the bounds of the solution stability. For `B<0` every thing works fine, but for `B>0` and `A>5` there exists a region where the solution fails. Using the interval `np.linspace(0.1,8,50)` in combination with `A=10, B=0.8` fails to give results between 0.7 and 2.2. The physical problem indicates that multiple solutions (I think up to 3) may exist in this region. I guess this is the reason for the crashes in the intermediate range of `k`. From a physical point of view this is the interesting region.